# How to self-join table in a way that every record is joined with the "previous" record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a MS SQL table that contains stock data with the following columns: `Id, Symbol, Date, Open, High, Low, Close`.

I would like to self-join the table, so I can get a day-to-day % change for `Close`.

I must create a query that will join the table with itself in a way that every record contains also the data from the previous session (be aware, that I cannot use yesterday's date).

My idea is to do something like this:

```
select * from quotes t1
inner join quotes t2
on t1.symbol = t2.symbol and
t2.date = (select max(date) from quotes where symbol = t1.symbol and date < t1.date)
```

However I do not know if that's the correct/fastest way. What should I take into account when thinking about performance? (E.g. will putting UNIQUE index on a (Symbol, Date) pair improve performance?)

There will be around 100,000 new records every year in this table. I am using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Can you show some sample data and throw it in a fiddle?

Comment: (1) Use a left join instead of an inner join, to handle new products. Then you have a general query, which can always be filtered to exclude records with a NULL Right-Hand-Side.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: I am only interested in rows that do not have NULL values, so INNER JOIN is there on purpose. Will LEFT JOIN improve performance? I do not think so...

Comment: Much easier/better performing in 2012 with `LAG/LEAD`

Comment: @MichalB.: That's fine; until you have to violate DRY becuase you didn't think ahead at the start.

Comment: @Martin Smith: I have used it in Oracle. Didn't know that MS SQL 2012 came with LAG/LEAD :). Thanks!

Comment: All of the solutions below are susceptible to exponential performance problems as the source table gets larger. This is not solving the exact same problem, but the techniques are similar: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals

Answer (score 9):

One option is to use a recursive cte (if I'm understanding your requirements correctly):

```
WITH RNCTE AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY date) rn
        FROM quotes
  ),
CTE AS (
  SELECT symbol, date, rn, cast(0 as decimal(10,2)) perc, closed
  FROM RNCTE
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT r.symbol, r.date, r.rn, cast(c.closed/r.closed as decimal(10,2)) perc, r.closed
  FROM CTE c 
    JOIN RNCTE r on c.symbol = r.symbol AND c.rn+1 = r.rn
  )
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY symbol, date
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5a82/9)

If you need a running total for each symbol to use as the percentage change, then easy enough to add an additional column for that amount -- wasn't completely sure what your intentions were, so the above just divides the current closed amount by the previous closed amount.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this w'd work in SQLite:

```
SELECT ..
FROM quotes t1, quotes t2
WHERE t1.symbol = t2.symbol
    AND t1.date < t2.date
GROUP BY t2.ID
    HAVING t2.date = MIN(t2.date)
```

Given SQLite is a simplest of a kind, maybe in MSSQL this will also work with minimal changes.

Answer (score 2):

Index on `(symbol, date)`

```
SELECT *
FROM quotes q_curr
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP(1) *
  FROM quotes
  WHERE symbol = q_curr.symbol
    AND date < q_curr.date
  ORDER BY date DESC
) q_prev
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use option with [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) ranking function

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT symbol, date, [Open], [High], [Low], [Close],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY date) AS Id
  FROM quotes
  )
  SELECT c1.Id, c1.symbol, c1.date, c1.[Open], c1.[High], c1.[Low], c1.[Close], 
         ISNULL(c2.[Close] / c1.[Close], 0) AS perc
  FROM cte c1 LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.symbol = c2.symbol AND c1.Id = c2.Id + 1
  ORDER BY c1.symbol, c1.date
```

For improving performance(avoiding sorting and RID Lookup) use this index

```
CREATE INDEX ix_symbol$date_quotes ON quotes(symbol, date) INCLUDE([Open], [High], [Low], [Close])
```

Simple demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62810/4)

Answer (score 1):

You do something like this:

```
with OrderedQuotes as
(
    select 
        row_number() over(order by Symbol, Date) RowNum, 
        ID, 
        Symbol, 
        Date, 
        Open, 
        High, 
        Low, 
        Close
      from Quotes
)
select
    a.Symbol,
    a.Date,
    a.Open,
    a.High,
    a.Low,
    a.Close,
    a.Date PrevDate,
    a.Open PrevOpen,
    a.High PrevHigh,
    a.Low PrevLow,
    a.Close PrevClose,

    b.Close-a.Close/a.Close PctChange

  from OrderedQuotes a
  join OrderedQuotes b on a.Symbol = b.Symbol and a.RowNum = b.RowNum + 1
```

If you change the last join to a left join you get a row for the first date for each symbol, not sure if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME
SELECT @Today = DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))

;WITH today AS
(
    SELECT  Id ,
            Symbol ,
            Date ,
            [OPEN] ,
            High ,
            LOW ,
            [CLOSE],
            DATEADD(DAY, -1, Date) AS yesterday 
    FROM quotes
    WHERE date = @today
)
SELECT *
FROM today
LEFT JOIN quotes yesterday ON today.Symbol = yesterday.Symbol
    AND today.yesterday = yesterday.Date
```

That way you limit your "today" results, if that's an option.

EDIT: The CTEs listed as other questions may work well, but I tend to be hesitant to use ROW_NUMBER when dealing with 100K rows or more. If the previous day may not always be yesterday, I tend to prefer to pull out the check for the previous day in its own query then use it for reference:

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME, @PreviousDay DATETIME
SELECT @Today = DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));
SELECT @PreviousDay = MAX(Date) FROM quotes  WHERE Date < @Today;
WITH today AS
(
    SELECT  Id ,
            Symbol ,
            Date ,
            [OPEN] ,
            High ,
            LOW ,
            [CLOSE]
    FROM quotes 
    WHERE date = @today
)
SELECT *
FROM today
LEFT JOIN quotes AS previousday
    ON today.Symbol = previousday.Symbol
    AND previousday.Date = @PreviousDay
```

Comment: I'm stuck using 2005 at the moment, which is why I've got that dateadd to figure out a date, there are simpler ways in 2008 and higher to do that.

Comment: This is on the right track, but you have to take weekends and holidays into account.

Comment: Weekends and holidays will require a calendar table. Much easier to populate this once than to write code that will calculate Easter, for example, on any given year.

Comment: This will also not work if the stock was not traded on the market in the previous session (and this is frequently the case). For such the % change should be calculated using the last session, when they were traded on the stock exchange (e.g. 2 days ago). So no one day for all stocks unfortunately...

Comment: @MichalB. Hmm, I wonder what's more important in that case, looking for the last day traded per symbol or looking at the last day any symbols were traded (i.e., if stock A was traded yesterday and stock B was not, should I still pull yesterday and just use ISNULLs to reflect that B had no change yesterday)?

Comment: @JasonWhisman the definition of % change is the change between today and the previous session when the stock was traded as the reference point.

Comment: @MichalB. Ah, then you *will* need to evaluate per row then; sgeddes answer is probably the best one for your situation then, since it's partitioning by symbol.

Answer (score 0):

What you had is fine.  I don't know if translating the sub-query into the join will help.  However, you asked for it, so the way to do it might be to join the table to itself once more.

```
select *
from quotes t1
inner join quotes t2
   on t1.symbol = t2.symbol and t1.date > t2.date
left outer join quotes t3
   on t2.symbol = t3.symbol and t2.date > t3.date
where t3.date is null
```

Comment: You might or might not want to group by the fields in T1 to collapse the results.  Since there is only one result of t1 and only one result of t2, and since you want the values for yesterday, maybe not.