# sql self join on previous record for audit change

Tags: sql

i am trying to get a sql query to return rows with the status of the previous time there was an audit log for the same account

like

```
create table aud
(
id int IDENTITY(1,1),
date_time datetime,
[user] varchar(20),
account varchar(20),
[status] char(2)
)
insert into aud values(getdate(),'guy','123456','00')
insert into aud values(getdate(),'guy','123456','01')
insert into aud values(getdate(),'guy','123456','02')
insert into aud values(getdate(),'guy','123456','00')
insert into aud values(getdate(),'guy','123456','04')
insert into aud values(getdate(),'guy','123456','01')
```

What i am looking for is a result that lists the previous account status something like 
date_time, user, account, status, previous_status

i tried

```
select a.*, b.*  from aud a
join aud b 
on a.account = (
select top 1 account from aud  where a.account = b.account and a.id > b.id order by date_time asc
)
```

but this joins more than just the previous one

Comment: Guessing this is SQL Server? Please add the appropriate tag with the version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to self-join table in a way that every record is joined with the "previous" record?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527423/how-to-self-join-table-in-a-way-that-every-record-is-joined-with-the-previous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012+, you can use `lag()` for a single column.  In you case, you want all columns so `outer apply` is better:

```
select a.*, aprev.*
from aud a outer apply
     (select top 1 a2.*
      from aud a2
      where a2.account = a.account and a2.id < a.id
      order by id desc
     ) aprev;
```

This assumes that the `id` orders the records the same way as `date_time`.  Your logic mixes the two -- I think it is better to stick to only one column for defining the previous record.

Comment: thanks, that does exactly what i am wanting to do, ill look up lag for interest's sake