# The first html row is not being displayed

Tags: php, mysql

So, let’s say I have 10 rows in my database. However, after the mysql query, only 9 rows are being displayed in the html table.
I need every row from the database to be displayed in the html table.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I’ll be here if I need to provide anymore details.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM periods";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQuery);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $out = $row['fell_out'];
        $in = $row['fell_in'];
        $sum = $row['sum'];
        $nextEstimate = $row['next_estimate'];
        $nextEstimateDays = $row['next_estimate_days'];
        $notes = $row['notes'];

        $sqlQueryLastDate = "SELECT * FROM (select * from periods WHERE id < $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS x ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
        $resultLastDate = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQueryLastDate);
        $resultCheckLastDate = mysqli_num_rows($resultLastDate);
        if ($resultCheckLastDate > 0) {
            while ($rowLastDate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultLastDate)) {
                $lastInDate = $rowLastDate['fell_in'];

                $sqlQueryCurrentDate = "SELECT * FROM (select * from periods WHERE id = $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) AS x ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
                $resultCurrentDate = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlQueryCurrentDate);
                $resultCheckCurrentDate = mysqli_num_rows($resultCurrentDate);
                if ($resultCheckCurrentDate > 0) {
                    while ($rowCurrentDate = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCurrentDate)) {
                        $currentOutDate = $rowCurrentDate['fell_out'];

                        $lastIn = new DateTime($lastInDate);
                        $currentOut = new DateTime($currentOutDate);
                        $intervalLastCurrent = $lastIn->diff($currentOut);
                        $elapsedLastCurrent = $intervalLastCurrent->format('%a days %h hours');
                        /*Why? Php is erasing everything after adding the above variable to the table...Entire first row gets erased!*/
                        echo "
                                <tr>    
                                    <td>".$id."</td>
                                    <td class='test'>".$elapsedLastCurrent."</td> 
                                    <td class='dateOutResult'>".$out."</td>
                                    <td class='dateInResult'>".$in."</td>
                                    <td class='sumHours'>".$sum."</td>
                                    <td class='nextEstimate'>".$nextEstimate." (".$nextEstimateDays.")</td>
                                    <td class='notes'>".$notes."</td>
                                </tr>";
                    } /*$sqlQueryCurrentDate*/
                }
            } /*$sqlQueryLastDate*/
        }
    } /*$sqlQuery*/
}
?>
```

Here's the live result: https://unidrones.co.za/periods

I am really new to mysql/php so I do not understand what I'm doing wrong. The nested queries is probably not the best approach to use, but I'm still learning, and any input will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What actually you want to achieve ?

Comment: Your logic is producing invalid HTML; see `<tr><tr>` in your final result.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sorry, what do you mean? When I view the page source, there is a <tr> element for the first row, but it's blank. What can I do to correct this?

Comment: [I mean precisely what I said; nothing more, nothing less.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lVsl.png)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Alright, that was a small mistake (all the tr elements were nested inside one tr) but that doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve here, and using nested queries is usually a sign that you might be better of using a join, but your problem seems to be that you are not printing anything when you do not get a subresult for e.g. `$sqlQueryLastDate` (the equivalent in sql would be to use a `join` when you need a `left join`). As I said, it's unclear what you are trying to do, but you might want to check there, e.g. add an `else` to `if ($resultCheckLastDate > 0) {` (and the other ones) and output something there to check if it's where you expect a specific row.

Comment: @Solarflare What I'm doing over there is just selecting a specific cell from the previous row of the current row, and a specific cell from the current row, using these results to calculate a new sum, which is stored in a variable, and will then be displayed in html later on. It's working fine as you may see in the link...Only problem is that the first row (with ID 1) is being hidden and only the rows with IDs 2 through 10 are displaying.... I need all rows (from ID 1 to ID 10) to display.. Please note that I'm pretty new to mysql so the logic you mentioned to me is difficult to understand.

Comment: Well, in that case my assumption seem to fit, as row 1 does not have a previous row, thus the 2nd (3rd?) query will not find anything, so it will not go into the `if`-block. You need to define what you want to printed when there is no predecessor. You can probably restructure your code or print in both the `if` and the `else` part; or rewrite your query into something like [Mysql Join with previous record](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/168147/117531) (you can add a new question if you want to do this and need help with that)

Comment: That makes sense...Of course if the code depends on a _previous_ row then there is bound to be some sort of error. I'll take your suggestion with the join-part and do my best. Thanks a million for your time :-)

Comment: Ok, good luck, and as I said, feel free to ask (a new question) if you are stuck. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39770330) is another thread with probably slightly simpler code that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your query is 
//select * from periods WHERE id < $id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
your first $id will be always equal id.